# Applet Java not working on IE9 but fine on Firefox

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet

i'm stuck with a little problem, i develop a java applet under windows 7 with JRE 1.6_0.37 and all work fine on IE9 and FF.

When we decide to test the application in target environment with a vmware pre-configured with client installation (IE9 and JRE1.6_0.20) we see that applet are not working ( i have a message like : Error : click here to have mmore informations on the top left corner of the page). When i check java console, i can see classnotfound. I try to download the jar directly (like `http://myhost/applet/my.jar`) and it work.

I decide to test with firefox and all work fine. But the target is IE9 :(

I check all parameter under IE to see if plugin are ok and activate and all seems to be ok.

why Firefox can retrieve JAR without problem and IE not?

i'm really stuck so if you can help me ;)

applet code:

```
<object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" width="100%" height="600" name="applet_appletObject" id="applet_appletObject"> 
<param name="code" value="fr.edf.mpv2.castor.applet.client.CastorAppletGraphique.class"> 
<param name="name" value="applet_appletObject/"> 
<param name="codebase" value="applet_appletObject/"> 
<param name="boxbgcolor" value="white"> 
<param name="scriptable" value="true"> 
<param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx512m -Xms96m"> 
<param name="mayscript" value="true"> 
<param name="codebase_lookup" value="false"> 
<param name="archive" value="/ctrweb/applet/castor-applet-client-02.00.00.jar,/ctrweb/applet/castor-applet-commun-02.00.00.jar,/ctrweb/applet/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,/ctrweb/applet/jcommon-1.0.13.jar,/ctrweb/applet/jfreechart-1.0.10.jar,/ctrweb/applet/jcalendar-1.3.3.jar"> 
<param name="cache_archive" value="/ctrweb/applet/castor-applet-client-02.00.00.jar,/ctrweb/applet/castor-applet-commun-02.00.00.jar,/ctrweb/applet/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,/ctrweb/applet/jcommon-1.0.13.jar,/ctrweb/applet/jfreechart-1.0.10.jar,/ctrweb/applet/jcalendar-1.3.3.jar"> 
<param name="cache_version" value="02.00.00, 02.00.00, 1.0.4.0, 1.0.D.0, 1.0.A.0"> <param name="appletName" value="applet_appletObject"/> 
<param name="resolutionY" value="1024"/> 
<param name="locale" value="fr"/> 
</object>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: You might want to post your applet embedding code and maybe a screenshot.

Comment: i have add html applet code, as you can see i declare my class and all needed jar. and as i say, all work fine with Firefox. so jar are present. Screenshot just show you the message Error : click here to have more information, and if i click on this message i have the java console that openned and i can see ClassNotFoundException CastorAppletGraphique.class. So if you see something wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's why IE doesn't have any friend, as user1071777 saysm some code and a screenshot will be usefull, but, have you tried to check it on other environment rather than VM, some members of my team can't start applets and/or javascripts from VM... maybe because they are made of tweaked OS versions